# Return labels when classifying images in FastAPI

Tags: python, api, tensorflow, deployment, fastapi

I am classifying images based on their types. In the last step I am returning the class which has the highest probability. Its working fine but when I am trying to map the labels , its showing me this error:

```
value is not a valid integer (type=type_error.integer)
```

saved model: https://gofile.io/d/myfFjR

sample image: https://gofile.io/d/myfFjR

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile, HTTPException
from PIL import Image
from pydantic import BaseModel
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from typing import List
import io
import numpy as np
import sys

# Load the model
filepath = 'C://Users//subhr//model.h5'
model = load_model(filepath, compile = True)

# Get the input shape for the model layer
input_shape = model.layers[0].input_shape

# Define the FastAPI app
app = FastAPI()

# Define the Response
class Prediction(BaseModel):
  filename: str
  contenttype: str
  prediction: List[float] = []
  likely_class: int



# Define the main route
@app.get('/')
def root_route():
  return { 'error': 'Use GET /prediction instead of the root route!' }


# Define the /prediction route
@app.post('/prediction/', response_model=Prediction)
async def prediction_route(file: UploadFile = File(...)):

  # Ensure that this is an image
  if file.content_type.startswith('image/') is False:
    raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail=f'File \'{file.filename}\' is not an image.')

  try:
    # Read image contents
    contents = await file.read()
    pil_image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(contents))

    # Resize image to expected input shape
    pil_image = pil_image.resize((input_shape[1], input_shape[2]))

    # Convert from RGBA to RGB *to avoid alpha channels*
    if pil_image.mode == 'RGBA':
      pil_image = pil_image.convert('RGB')

    # Convert image into grayscale *if expected*
    if input_shape[3] and input_shape[3] == 1:
      pil_image = pil_image.convert('L')

    # Convert image into numpy format
    numpy_image = np.array(pil_image).reshape((input_shape[1], input_shape[2], input_shape[3]))

    # Scale data (depending on your model)
    numpy_image = numpy_image / 255

    # Generate prediction
    prediction_array = np.array([numpy_image])
    predictions = model.predict(prediction_array)
    prediction = predictions[0]
    likely_class = np.argmax(prediction)

    return {
      'filename': file.filename,
      'contenttype': file.content_type,
      'prediction': prediction.tolist(),
      'likely_class': lambda x: 'Driving License' if likely_class == 0  else ('Pancard' if likely_class == 1 else('Passport' if likely_class == 2 else 'Voter Id')) #this is where I am getting an error
    }
  except:
    e = sys.exc_info()[1]
    raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Prediction(BaseModel):
    filename: str
    contenttype: str
    prediction: List[float] = []
    likely_class: int
```

You're saying that `likely_class` is an int, and then on your function `likely_class` assumes a string value:

```
      'likely_class': lambda x: 'Driving License' if likely_class == 0  else ('Pancard' if likely_class == 1 else('Passport' if likely_class == 2 else 'Voter Id'))
```

Just modify your `Prediction` to accept string or your function output.